# iOS NSTimer stops when application enters inactive

Tags: ios, ios7, nstimer

I have been doing some reading - I am making a stopwatch style app and out of habbit I always lock my screen. I want me app to continue to countdown though.

So it seems inactive stops NSTimers. I tried adding the UIBackgroundModes with value audio - which seems to turn into "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay" yet the timer still stops when I lock my screen.

Can somebody talk me through this! iOS7

Comment: Please do some searching. There are countless existing questions discussing this topic.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+stopwatch+background

Comment: These are not really solutions rmaddy - As I need to play a sound a particular point during my app being in the background. These solutions mostly involve calculating the difference in date time on the observer events - which in my case is not what I want. I want the timer to continue to countdown from 60 and output audio at certain points towards 0.

Comment: Then so some searching on how to do some processing in the background. Look into local notifications as one solution.

Comment: Need more direct help rmaddy - im finding it really hard!

Comment: You make this problem sound easy to solve as if there is a easy to go to post to find the answer - if its that easy highlight it for me...I dont see anybody actually having solved this problem and detailing exactly how it was solved.

Comment: Look at local notifications.  Learn how to read the specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to run timers in the background. Apple takes steps to prevent it because it drains the user's battery.

Unfortunately you really can't write a stopwatch or timer style app like Apple's. Apple has access to system functions that third party apps don't, and their apps don't have to play by the same rules.

Comment: Ill just have to warn my users about entering locked mode in this case - pity! Restrictive apple :@ - this provides a bad user experience for this kind of application which would be quite useful to other people. I suppose having a decent battery life is the reason for the protection which is fair enough.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy - So it's "My way or the highway"?  (Look into [local notifications](http://tinyurl.com/p7xrqn8).)

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely build a stopwatch app that supports locking the screen / backgrounding the app.

The trick is to simply record the date when the stopwatch was started. Every time you need to update the display (e.g., on your timer callback), you simply compute the time elapsed since the start date.

Here is a simple view controller that implements this behaviour:

```
@implementation StopwatchViewController
{
    NSTimer *timer;
    NSDate *timerStartDate;

    UILabel *timeLabel;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create a label
    timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    timeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    timeLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    timeLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0f];
    [self.view addSubview:timeLabel];

    // Start stopwatch
    [self startStopwatch];
}

#pragma mark - Time Control

- (void) startStopwatch
{
    // Record when the timer started
    timerStartDate = [NSDate date];

    // Schedule a timer to update our label
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(timerUpdate:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void) stopStopwatch
{
    [timer invalidate];

    timerStartDate = nil;
    timer = nil;
}

#pragma mark - Timer Callback

- (void) timerUpdate:(id)sender
{
    // Compute the time interval since timer start
    NSTimeInterval runTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:timerStartDate];

    timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", runTime];
}

@end
```

Regarding counting down / alarming the user when it hits a certain time, this can be done using local notifications. If you are counting down from a fixed time then schedule the local notification to take place that far in the future.